# Two laptops separately detected another IPv4 mDNS stack running on the host

Tags: networking, avahi

Yesterday I encountered a problem on both of my two laptops (both using Ubuntu, one is 20.04.5, one is 22.04).

The problem was a crash popup "The application Passwords and Keys has closed unexpectedly". One had a crash around the time I came home and opened it (it was running the whole day). The second one got the error about an hour later, about 4 minutes after I powered it on.

After I checked the crash logs of seahorse, I found following on both of them (times differ):

```
JournalErrors:
 -- Logs begin at Tue 2022-10-11 13:39:55 CEST, end at Fri 2023-06-02 20:11:54 CEST. --
 Jun 02 20:08:28 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
 Jun 02 20:08:28 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
 Jun 02 20:08:28 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
 Jun 02 20:08:28 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
 Jun 02 20:08:29 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
 Jun 02 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: *** WARNING: Detected another IPv4 mDNS stack running on this host. This makes mDNS unreliable and is thus not recommended. ***
 Jun 02 20:08:32 ntb seahorse[5992]: failure communicating with to avahi: Daemon connection failed
 Jun 02 20:08:32 ntb org.gnome.seahorse.Application[5992]: seahorse: glib-watch.c:195: timeout_update: Assertion `!t->dead' failed.
 Jun 02 20:08:33 ntb dbus-daemon[729]: Unknown group "power" in message bus configuration file
```

then I checked the syslog and found this for avahi:

(19.168.A.B is an address that has appeared before)
(SAME_IPV6 t00)

```
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv6 with address <SAME_IPV6>.
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: New relevant interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Registering new address record for <SAME_IPV6> on <WLP_INTERFACE>.*.
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4 with address <19.168.A.B>.
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: New relevant interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:04:33 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Registering new address record for <19.168.A.B> on <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:08:28 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv6 with address <SAME_IPV6>.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4 with address <19.168.A.B>.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[721]: avahi-daemon 0.7 exiting.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Succeeded.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Process 721 died: No such process; trying to remove PID file. (/run/avahi-daemon//pid)
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 115) and group 'avahi' (GID 121).
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: avahi-daemon 0.7 starting up.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Successfully called chroot().
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: *** WARNING: Detected another IPv4 mDNS stack running on this host. This makes mDNS unreliable and is thus not recommended. ***
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv6 with address <SAME_IPV6>.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: New relevant interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4 with address <19.168.A.B>.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: New relevant interface <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: New relevant interface lo.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: New relevant interface lo.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Registering new address record for <SAME_IPV6> on <WLP_INTERFACE>.*.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Registering new address record for <19.168.A.B> on <WLP_INTERFACE>.IPv4.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Registering new address record for ::1 on lo.*.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Registering new address record for 127.0.0.1 on lo.IPv4.
Jun  2 20:08:32 ntb seahorse[5992]: failure communicating with to avahi: Daemon connection failed
Jun  2 20:08:33 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Server startup complete. Host name is ntb.local. Local service cookie is 264471101.
Jun  2 20:09:43 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Files changed, reloading.
Jun  2 20:09:43 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun  2 20:09:43 ntb avahi-daemon[167503]: Files changed, reloading.
```

What could have caused this to happen on both laptops? Should I be concerned? I am new to mDNS. Both laptops are on the same network, together with 2 smart devices.I didn't configure **avahi** on any of them and I barely use the first laptop. Thanks